# postgresql 14 - s.PGSQL.5432 no such file

Tags: postgresql, sockets

Installed ubuntu 22.04, postgresql v 14.9 - everything worked correctly. Rebooted the system, got an error:

```
"connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql//.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?"
```

Further attempts at self-correction resulted in this

```
       $service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-09-08 08:40:41 MSK; 1h 0min ago
Main PID: 3142 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CPU: 3ms
systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.



       $pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log



       $sudo systemctl start postgresql@14-main
Job for postgresql@14-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@14-main.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql@14-main.service" for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

We're looking at the log

```
journalctl -xeu postgresql@14-main.service
```

see

```
FATAL:could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
```

You need to go into the config and fix `shared_buffers` or `huge_pages=on` (in my case the buffer was too big)

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you solved your problem. But info about the real problem is missing. The default setting for `shared_buffers = 128MB` and you just installed postgreSQL. Question: Why was it set too high? what value are you using now ? Do you know the minimum is 128Mb  (see: [docs about shared_buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY))